# Mac Eject USB Disk from Java program

Tags: java, macos, command-line

I'm trying to eject a USB thumb drive on Mac from a Java program.  I've tried umount and diskutil eject and neither works.  I get an exit code of 1 from both.  If I physically pull the drive out, Mac OS X gives me the standard warning.

My code:

```
log.debug( "going to eject targetRoot.getPath()=" + targetRoot.getPath() );
String command = "diskutil eject " + targetRoot.getPath().replace( " ", "\\ " );
log.debug( "about to run command=" + command );
int exitCode = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command ).waitFor();
log.debug( "exitCode=" + exitCode );
```

The output:

```
going to eject targetRoot.getPath()=/Volumes/NO NAME
about to run command=diskutil eject /Volumes/NO\ NAME
exitCode=1
```

The man pages indicate that you can use the mounted path or the path to the device as an argument for umount or diskutil eject.

If I copy the command to the terminal and run it, then it works perfectly.  I suspect it's something related to the environment, but as you can see I'm not sending an envp to the exec method.

What's a programmer gotta do to make the eject/unmount work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than Runtime.exec()? It lets you specify each of the arguments precisely, and it also lets you construct an environment.

...or at least use the form of [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) specifying an array of arguments rather than a string.

I would guess that your escaping of spaces isn't working -- the convenience form of [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) handles spaces using StringTokenizer and probably isn't as smart as most shells.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  I switched to using an array of strings.  I also had to remove the replacement of the space with a "\ ".